# Flask request seems to be None for the Google-Bot

Tags: python, flask

I wrote a website with Flask; it returns different results for mobile and desktop. I check the platform using `request.user_agent.platform` on the server.

Here's my code to return different websites for android, desktop and other mobile devices:

```
if request.user_agent.platform == "android":
    ismobile = True
    # do something when the user is on android
for pf in ["iphone", "iPad", "ipad", "Windows Phone OS", "windows phone os", "BlackBerry", "windows phone", "Windows Phone", "WindowsPhone", "android"]:
    if pf in request.user_agent.platform:
        ismobile = True
        # do something when the user is on any other mobile device
if not ismobile:
    # do something when the user is on desktop
```

So far, this code works. But when the Google-Bot sends a request, a ValueError is thrown:

```
TypeError
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

(Tested with Google Markup Tools, here's the [full stack trace](https://markuphelper.googleusercontent.com/webmasters/markup-helper/RenderFrame/007c195751c507e03dd8c6fa9d72f44935af91d3848643377b07703d0e35b4d90aadc708bf61482f6a7d69089ca0bff5cfb8b20b98636dc13c?xpc=%7B%22cn%22:%22BmB1A1KINo%22,%22tp%22:null,%22osh%22:null,%22pru%22:%22https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/u/1/tagger/relay.html%22,%22ppu%22:%22https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/u/1/tagger/blank.html%22,%22lpu%22:%22https://markuphelper.googleusercontent.com/blank.html%22%7D)).

It seems that something is None when Google visits my page. Does anyone know how I can prevent my app from throwing the error?

**EDIT:** I forgot: The error is thrown when I access the request. Code like `if request is None:` still produces the Error.

Comment: Why not test for `is None` then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried, but the Error is still thrown.

Comment: @Functino thanks, the edit is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown here:

```
if pf in request.user_agent.platform:
```

where `platform` is expected to be an object supporting a containment test. `None` is not such an object, so test for it explicitly:

```
platform = request.user_agent.platform
if platform and pf in platform:
```

Comment: Now I know why the fixing didn't work: I "sync" my code with a raspberrypi. On this raspi was no space left, so it did nothing. The error came because it didn't fix on the server.